# Random File Generator Loop does not generate correct amount of files

Tags: c++

I'm using `ofstream` to generate random files with text stored inside them. However, it seems like the `fileNum` variable which is supposed to specify how many `.txt` files to generate is not working. The number of `.txt` files generated has a varying difference from the actual specified amount. Sometimes its 4 off(or 3 or 2), and sometimes it gets it right. I'm not quite sure what's wrong, I'm very new to C++

```
string genRandStr(int len, int seed) {

    // Add a seed, so a different random number is generated each time
    srand(time(seed));
    char alphaNum[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

    int strlen = sizeof(alphaNum) - 1;
    string randStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        randStr += alphaNum[rand() % strlen];
    }

    return randStr;
}
//main function

int main()
{
    int fileNum;
    cout << "FILEWARS - SAFE VERSION - USE WITH CARE" << endl;
    cout << "Made By: David Yue" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the amount of files you wish to create: ";
    cin >> fileNum;
    if (cin.fail()) {
        cout << "Value must be an integer." << endl;
    }
    if (fileNum >= 30) {

        cout << "SAFE VERSION RESTRICTION: File Amount may not exceed 30" << endl;
        main();
    } else {
        ofstream file1;
        stringstream fileName;
        for (int i = 0; i <= fileNum; i++) {

            fileName << genRandStr(6, time(i) ) << ".txt";

            file1.open(fileName.str());;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                file1 << genRandStr(100, time(i)) << "\n";
            }

            file1.close();
            file1.clear();
            fileName.str("");
            fileName.clear();
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `fileNum` to verify it matches what you expect?

Comment: @John3136 Let me give that a shot

Comment: hmm. I just figured that problem out @FirstStep, and FileNum is printing out correctly. However the bug still occurs..

Comment: @DavidYue Why are you calling `main` recursively?  This is not legal C++ syntax.  Use a while loop instead.

Comment: @DavidYue And if you really want unique names, generate GUID or UUID's as the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *generating* the same file name so at some point it does not create a new file, it over ride the old one instead. I assume that you want differnet/unique name for every file so I suggest that you choose any base name (example *MyFile* ) and add `+` a `count` beside it. Initialize your count by 1 and then increment your `count` on every iteration/new file. Result should get you unique names for all files example: `file1`, `file2`, `file3`.. etc

Or, if you still need to use Random Generator, then `srand(time(seed));` (and despite how did you choose `seed`s value) should be called only once during the whole program execution and *not* on every call. therefore, use `Null` instead of your `seed` and just state globally `srand(time(Null));` at the top of your code. Initializing it *only once* will get you the ability to use `rand();` freely and guarantee you get different numbers every call. But watch out for your `% strlen` because strings might still get the same `sizeof`.

Comment: Seems like the `count` problem fixed it, I removed the random filenames

Comment: @DavidYue Or add your `i+1` to a any name inside your loop. Glad we were able to help :)